# Windows Advanced Firewall: Why is Port 808 open by default?

Tags: windows, firewall

I'm tuning up the Windows Advanced Firewall on my web server.  All I need is 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS) and 808 (net.tcp).  I noticed that I needed to create a rule for 80 and 443 before my application would work, but not for 808.  In fact, it wasn't until I created a specific rule to block 808 that my application **stopped** working.

Can anyone explain why I needed a specific rule to block 808 before it would stop traffic?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Port 808 is used by the Net.TCP Port Sharing service, associated with Internet Information Services through the Windows Communication Foundation. Without it, IIS generally will not work.

Long Answer:

Port 808 is used by the Net.TCP Port Sharing service, associated with the Windows Communication Foundation. Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is a framework for building service-oriented applications.

Port Sharing is commonly used by network applications that utilise the HTTP protocol as it is (on most networks) allowed by default.

A few examples in which WCF may be used are:

- A secure service to process business transactions.
- A service that supplies current data to others, such as a traffic
  report or other monitoring service.
- A chat service that allows two people to communicate or exchange data
  in real time.
- A dashboard application that polls one or more services for data and
  presents it in a logical presentation.
- Exposing a workflow implemented using Windows Workflow Foundation as
  a WCF service.
- A Silverlight application to poll a service for the latest data
  feeds.

> "Many network applications make use of the HTTP protocol because most firewalls are configured by default to allow traffic on TCP port 80."

Therefore, Microsoft needed to implement a way to allow multiple applications running through IIS to share the same port, thus the concept of Net.TCP Port Sharing was born.

Note: I sourced this information through my own research. If you require a more detailed explanation as to how I gathered this information and came to this info, please do feel free to send me a private message and I will be more than happy to explain in detail.

***** ORIGINAL ANSWER *****

Port 808 is the Microsoft Net.TCP Port Sharing Service.

"Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) provides a new TCP-based network protocol (net.tcp://) for high-performance communication. WCF also introduces a new system component, the Net.TCP Port Sharing Service that enables net.tcp ports to be shared across multiple user processes."

Sources:

1. List of TCP and UDP port numbers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers, accessed 24 December 2016.
2. Net.TCP Port Sharing, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772(v=vs.110).aspx, accessed 24 December 2016.

Comment: This is a question about the firewall.  How is this answer remotely related to the original question?

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury, I did my best to answer it. I revised it today to provide a more detailed response which may provide some clarity. If you feel that I have answered your question, please do upvote it. But I would reconsider the used of the word "remotely" _which_ _could_ _imply_ that I do not know what I am talking about.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok, the answer to the question is _You need a specific rule to block 808 before it would stop traffic **because it is enabled by default by Microsoft**_. However, that just begs the question _Why does Microsoft enable port 808 by default?_ If you want to be pedantic, you're right, it does **not** answer the original question. However, it **does** answer the underlying question. I know this is late and probably moot, but I felt it needed said.